# Ruby: Initializing a hash: Assign values, throw on undefined key access, and freeze, all at once?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I want to initialize a new hash, such that:

- The hash is assigned a specific set of initial key-value pairs;
- The hash is configured to raise an error if an attempt is made to retrieve the value for an undefined key;
- The hash is frozen (can't be further modified).

Is there an elegant Ruby-ish way to do this setup all at once?

I'm aware that this can be done in three separate lines, e.g.:

```
COIN_SIDES = { heads: 'heads', tails: 'tails' }
COIN_SIDES.default_proc = -> (h, k) { raise KeyError, "Key '#{k}' not found" }
COIN_SIDES.freeze
```

Comment: If you use `fetch` instead of `[]` you'll get a `KeyError` automatically for absent keys.

Comment: You can write a whole Ruby program in a single line. Just use semicolons as separator instead of newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by initializing hash with default_proc and then adding components with merge!:

```
h = Hash.new{|hash, key| raise KeyError, "Key '#{key}' not found"}.merge!({ heads: 'heads', tails: 'tails' }).freeze
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is terribly elegant, but one way to achieve this in one (long) line is by using [`.tap`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap):

```rb
COIN_SIDES = { heads: 'heads', tails: 'tails' }.tap { |cs| cs.default_proc = -> (h, k) { raise KeyError, "Key '#{k}' not found" } }.tap(&:freeze)
```

This approach does at least avoid the [`RuboCop: Freeze mutable objects assigned to constants [Style/MutableConstant]`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/MutableConstant) warning generated when running the [RuboCop](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop) linter on the 3-line version of the code from the original question, above.

Comment: [Kernel#freeze](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze) returns its receiver, so you can replace `.tap(&:freeze)` with `.freeze`.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish most of this functionality by making a custom class, the only downside being it's not really a hash, so you'd need to explicitly add on extra functionality like `.keys`, `each`, etc if needed:

```
class HashLike
  def initialize(hsh)
    singleton_class.attr_reader *hsh.keys
    hsh.each { |k,v| instance_variable_set "@#{k}", v }
  end
end

hashlike = HashLike.new(some_value: 1)
hashlike.some_value # 1
hashlike.missing_value # NoMethodError
hashlike.some_value = 2 # NoMethodError
```

Another similar way:

```
class HashLike2
  def initialize(hsh)
    @hsh = hsh
  end

  def [](key)
    @hsh.fetch(key)
  end
end

hashlike2 = HashLike2.new(some_value: 1)
hashlike2[:some_value] # 1
hashlike2[:missing_value] # KeyError
hashlike2[:some_value] = 2 # NoMethodError
```

But in my opinion, there's not much a reason to do this. You can easily move your original 3 lines into a method somewhere out of the way, and then it doesn't matter if it's 3 lines or 1 anymore.